# To force browsers to get latest css in asp.net application

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

To force browsers to get latest css files in asp.net application, I got the following code. But when i used the code CSS is not versioning. Js worked fine with same code. but css shows the file without version like abc.css

I wrote the method in controller and how can I pass to Layout.cshtml in the place of Scripts

```
public static class JavascriptExtension {
public static MvcHtmlString IncludeVersionedJs(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename) {
    string version = GetVersion(helper, filename);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type='text/javascript' src='" + filename + version + "'></script>");
}

private static string GetVersion(this HtmlHelper helper, string filename){
    var context = helper.ViewContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
    if (context.Cache[filename] == null) {
        var physicalPath = context.Server.MapPath(filename);
        var version = "?v=" +
          new System.IO.FileInfo(physicalPath).LastWriteTime
            .ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
        context.Cache.Add(physicalPath, version, null,
          DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.Zero,
          CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
        context.Cache[filename] = version;
        return version;
    }
    else {return context.Cache[filename] as string;}
}
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)?

Comment: it is in asp.net mvc 3

Comment: See [Bundling and minification in MVC3 and Asp.Net 4.0](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/0a9M050113-Bundling-and-minification-in-MVC3-and-Asp.Net-4.0.html). Hth.